# How to ask an interviewer's name

Tags: interviewing, name

Sometimes, I have faced an interview where the panel does not introduce themselves. The panel could consist of one or more than one interviewer.

Is it rude to ask the name of the interviewers? If not, when should a candidate ask? At the end or at the beginning? What should the correct format be, without offending the panel?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

> Is it rude to ask the name of the interviewers?

**No**, it is not rude to ask.  Typically introductions are done at the beginning of the interview out of courtesy.

> At the end or at the beginning?

I would suggest **neither**, and take a more go with the flow approach.  As the interview progresses, and you are asked a question, I would say this before answering to those who did not introduce themselves:

"*Sorry I did not catch your name...*"

Usually the interviewer will then provide their name, and you can then proceed in using it.

Comment: "I would suggest neither" Why? My experience is it's one of the first things that comes up anyway.

Comment: @Mast As I said in my answer, I would suggest a more go with the flow style when introductions aren't properly made.  In my experience this is much less disruptive to the flow of the interview.

Comment: I have an unusual name, and I'm really bad at remembering people's names. So personally, if an interviewee asked me for my name even _multiple_ times, I wouldn't care. No need to be subtle about it, either: "I'm sorry, I forget, what was your name again?" Interviews are stressful, tiring, and involve constant context switching. I know that, and I would consider it extremely reasonable for someone to forget my name multiple times in the course of 60 minutes. Mine is probably the fifth name they've tried to remember today, under tough conditions.

Comment: @MisterPositive It is so simple and I keep wondering why I complicate such things.

Comment: When someone tells you their name, if it's not awkward, repeat it back to them. It will often help you to remember it. Similarly, write the names down. You'll probably want to refer back to them later.

Answer (score 9):

> Is it rude to ask the name of the interviewers?

- It is not rude at all. Social norms here, but don't ask them 6 times during the interview. That's just obnoxious.

> If not, when should a candidate ask?

- Alright, asking at the beginning right when they introduce themselves is the best. I then make mental pictures of their faces and associate those with their names. Also, jot down their first name and what color shirt/tie/hair etc. they are wearing on the paper you should have brought with you. That also makes you look prepared.

> At the end or at the beginning?

- Beginning. If you can remember them (all). But nothing wrong with asking at the end. Remember, these interviewers know that position you are in, and they understand if you can't memorize everyone's names the first try.

> What should the correct format be, without offending the panel?

- Don't worry about offending the panel. If you don't recall someone's name, simply ask "What was your name again sir/mam?"

One caveat to my answer: A job where remembering names is regarded as important, such as a sales position, the hiring employees could regard your lack of name memory and label you a poor candidate for the position.

Comment: *Alright, asking at the beginning right when they introduce themselves is the best.* -- Based on what?   Also, what if they don't introduce themselves?  Usually someone leads the interview process and on occasion they don't all get the intro...

Comment: @MisterPositive Good point. If they don't introduce themselves, make sure that when you eventually hand them your business card/resume, shake their hand and kindly ask for their contact information.